# Android Google Maps V2 Route

Tags: android, google-maps

my question is how i can control the dynamic icon, is it in route or not? If it is not i want to draw new polyline to target location. I hope you could understand me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "control the dynamic icon"? Can you clarify your goal and share your code and what you have done so far. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I am sorry for this and i want to check the marker on the route or not, if it is not i want to draw new polyline to target location from current location. I have no code, just i am waiting idea.